# Figuring out installation method for AWS CLI on Mac

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I would like to update AWS CLI to the latest version on Mac.  According to [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html),

> If you are updating to the latest version, use the same installation
> method that you used in your current version.

But I don't remember which method I used to install the current version.  How can I check?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. Those instructions say that, for the Mac: "In your browser, download the macOS pkg file: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.pkg"

Comment: `stat /usr/local/aws-cli/aws`

Comment: Thank you @JohnRotenstein.  I thought it meant I had to match with the previous method.  I don't remember if I did via GUI installer or command line, but I just did GUI and it worked.